# C++, reference "constructor"

Tags: c++

```
template<typename T, typename R>
T f(R &r) { return T(r); }

int main() {
    int o;
    f<int&>(o);
}
```

Is this ok?  Comeau didnt complain, so I assume `int&(...)` form is fine?

reason example:

```
    typename boost::mpl::if_c<
        (rank == 1),
        reference,
        tensor_ref<typename detail::array_ref<A>::type>
        >::type
    operator[](const int &i) {
        typedef typename boost::mpl::if_c<
            (rank == 1),
            reference,
            tensor_ref<typename detail::array_ref<A>::type>
                >::type T;
        return T(detail::array_ref<A>::generate(this->data()));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine, it acts like a cast from `int&` to `int&`, and returns `int&`, referring back to `o`.

I'm not sure what purpose this would serve, though.

Comment: sometimes i want function to return reference, sometimes some class with explicit constructor taking r as argument.  hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @aaa: It still doesn't explain why you need a dedicated function for that. What's wrong with just writing `T(r)` in places where you would use `f<T>(r)`?

Comment: @aaa: Sorry, but I'm still not seeing the point of `f<T>()`. What's wrong with the code snippet you provided that requires the `f<T>()` function? It seems fine to me. Is `f<T>()` supposed to replace the `return T(...);` statement? If so, what's wrong with it?

Comment: @aa: Yeah, sorry, I don't see it either.

Comment: @GMan even in the sample above?

Comment: @aaa: No, GMan and I can't see the need for `f<T>()` even in your code sample that you nicely provided. Again, what is the purpose of `f<T>()` with respect to your code sample? It appears that it's supposed to replace the `return` statement but the `return` statement that you have looks fine to me. Can you provide a code sample that actually uses `f<T>()`? Is `f<T>()` required for successful compilation? I really don't see why you need the `f<T>()` function.

Answer (score 0):

It is expanding to...

```
int& f(int & r){

   return int& (r);

}
```

which turns into...

```
int & r(o);
```

which is completely legal c++.